# How to add a HTML comment into a React component without extra nodes?

Tags: reactjs

The idea is simple: I want to add a html comment into a rendered react without extra nodes.

This is my code:

```
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <!-- i want this comment to be here -->
        {items}
        <!-- i want this other comment to be here -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The only way I found is using this:

```
<li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '<!-- comment -->' }} />
```

But this one adds me a new DOM node, which I don't need (nor want). So basically what I need is to generate markup like this:

```
<ul>
  <!-- comment -->
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

There is a way of doing this and I'm missing anything?

**Edit: What problem I'm trying to solve?**

The idea here is that I'm using React to only edit the content, which will be saved into DB as HTML. I know is not ideal, but we're talking WordPress here, so we have some wiggle room :)

Anyhow, the problem I'm trying to solve is that I want to create some kind of „hook” to the future me so I could alter the result dynamically (with a search & replace from PHP, so pseudoselectors aren't really useful here). HTML comments is the only way I could think that won't affect the output if is not used.

Thanks!

Comment: html comments ***are*** dom nodes when rendered by browser and have a `nodeType`. Doubt you can render them without there being a node created. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl Does CSS [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo elements also add nodes? I don't know, just asking if they are..

Comment: @ArupRakshit No. Pseudo selectors are not part of the dom

Comment: @lonut will that work ^ then?

Comment: might also consider `data-` attributes

Comment: Demo to show this has nothing to do with react creating nodes and is all about how browser handles comments http://jsfiddle.net/pfdLzknr/1/

Comment: I am trying to understand why `dom` is so costly.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit why is that costly? Is simply text you can't see but it's still accessible. Lots involved in painting the rendered dom. All text is in nodes also

Comment: No I am asking if it is costly to keep DOM which will not be viewed in browser, so that OP wants to not add.. I am just trying to understand what is the reason of the OP's thought.

Comment: @ArupRakshit ahhh yes...me too. Considering react dev tools available those comments seem like a trivial problem

Comment: OP added an usecase :)

Comment: @charlietfl: yeah, but maybe I understood React wrongly, but... since I have an `ul` as a parent, shouldn't be that enough?

Comment: I read your use case and really don't understand what it has to do with html comments or the problem you have with comments as nodes

Comment: Actually the solution offered by @Prasanna works great, but for some reason he decided to remove his answer. :/

Answer (score -3):

You can simply use javascript comments with curly braces.

Example:

```
render( ){
 return (
   <div>
     {/* LIST STARTS HERE */}
     <ul>

     </ul>
     {/* LIST ENDS HERE */}
   </div>
 )
```

Comment: Those won't render as OP is asking